# Prepositional confusions!

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> "My friend insisted me on reading your notes."

Is this sentence correct? I have been debating between the aforementioned and:

> "My friend insisted me to read your notes."

Would the first one be grammatically acceptable?

**Edit:**

I recently texted that line to someone. Here's what I'm trying to say: "My friend suggested/ asked me to read your notes."

Comment: Which of the following ideas are you trying to express:  My friend insisted that I read my notes.  My friend insisted that I let him read my notes. My friend insists that you let me read your notes. My friend insisted that I ask you to read your notes. Or something else?

Comment: Perhaps also consider: *"My friend insisted on me reading your notes."* :)

Comment: @Jennifer- How many people total are involved in your conversation? The friend doing the insisting, you, and the friend with the notes?

Comment: @Jim Only two people are involved. The person with the notes and I. My friend who is insisting is a third person.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest: My friend insisted that I read (his/her) notes.

Comment: Thanks! :) But used the first one already! Is it noticeable? :/

Comment: Yes, as evidenced by my confusion in what you were trying to say.  I doubt your friend will disown you though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically I think what you want to say is:

> *My friend insisted that I read your notes*.

The word *insisted* doesn't take "me" as an object. If there's only one piece of cake left, and my friend wanted me to eat it, I would report that by saying:

> She insisted that I eat the cake.

and not:

> <strike>She insisted me eat the cake</strike>.

Getting back to your question title – notice how there is **no** preposition!

You should also realize, though, that *insisted* is a much stronger word than *suggested*. If your friend *suggested* that you read the notes, that just means it was an idea for you to consider. If your friend *insisted* that you read the notes, it means your friend wasn't ready to accept "No" as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per grammar, you don't insist somebody to do something. However, in formal English, you can insist on somebody  doing something e.g.'"My friend insisted my/me reading your notes". Usually, we say "my friend insisted that I read your notes". It's also correct to say in BE that "My friend insisted that I should read your notes".
Please refer to Oxford Learners' Dictionary to look up "insist".

So both the sentences presented have not been formed properly.